# Преобразование типов с проверкой

Tags: java, преобразование-типов

Есть такой код

```
int i = 300;
byte b = (byte)i;
```

Можно ли как-то его заставить генерировать исключение при обнаружении, что `i` не помещается в байт? Или только так?

```
int i = 300;
if (i < Byte.MIN_VALUE || i > Byte.MAX_VALUE)
    throw new ArithmeticException();
byte b = (byte)i;
```

Comment: Если учесть, что в java нет перегрузки операторов, параметров по умолчанию, и иного синтаксического сахара, то думаю, что нет, нельзя заставить такой код генерировать исключение. Более того, если кто-то докажет, что это действительно можно сделать, я буду очень сильно удивлён)

Comment: Можно таким костылем: byte b = Byte.valueOf (i + "") получите NumberFormatException

Comment: @АлександрПоташев Думал над этим. Тогда уже так `byte b = Byte.parseByte(Integer.toSring(i))` Но гонять числа в строки и обратно - костыль еще тот. Проще будет объявить какой-нибудь отдельный метод конвертации с проверкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть та же, но на мой взгляд покрасивее, хотя и менее понятно =)
Имя метода взял по подобию `Math.toIntExact(long)`

```
byte toByteExact(int i){
    byte b = (byte)i;
    if (i != b)
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    else 
        return b;
}
```

Comment: Да. Красиво. Особенно, если убрать `else` :)